# Java concurrency in Practice - Sample 5.3

Tags: java, concurrency, iteration

As stated in listing 5.3

```
for(int i=0;i<vector.size();i++)
    doSomething(vecotr.get(i));
```

> Even though the iteration in Listing 5.3 can throw an exception, this
>   doesn't mean Vector isn't threadͲsafe. The state of the Vector is
>   still valid and the exception is in fact in conformance with its
>   specification. However, that something as mundane as fetching the last
>   element or iteration throw an exception is clearly undesirable.

Above statement is unclear to me.If during the iteration vector is modified and it can throw exception, **How the Vector's state will be valid**.

Answer (score 0):

Its not synchronized access to the vector, that means some other thread can remove element on i position while doSomething is accessing it, this will throw outOfBoundsException if i index is not within a bounds.**BUD** that doesnt mean Vector class is not in valid state, you just dont want to experience over iteration this behaviour, thats why you use synchronization to let only one thread access it at a time.

Hence code sample 5.4.

```
synchronized (vector) {
for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
doSomething(vector.get(i));
}
```

Client side locking.

You lock vector

> Every object has an intrinsic lock associated with it. By convention,
>   a thread that needs exclusive and consistent access to an object's
>   fields has to acquire the object's intrinsic lock before accessing
>   them, and then release the intrinsic lock when it's done with them. A
>   thread is said to own the intrinsic lock between the time it has
>   acquired the lock and released the lock. As long as a thread owns an
>   intrinsic lock, no other thread can acquire the same lock. The other
>   thread will block when it attempts to acquire the lock.

Even tho some collection is thread safe you can get into indexOutOfBounds exception, bud state of the collection will be valid.